# PHP Variable Rules

Tags: php, variables, web, error-handling, undefined

I've got a simple question about variables in PHP! 
How can i make a global final variable? I wanna have few information in a php-file. I've got some functions there who return the information.

```
<?php

static $titleOfPage = "Opinion";
static $autor = "Daniel";
static $description = "blablabla";
static $keywords = "blablabla";

function getTitleOfPage(){
    return $titleOfPage;
} 
function getAutorOfPage(){
    return $autor;
} 
function getDescriptionOfPage(){
    return $description;
} 
function getKeywordsOfPage(){
    return $keywords;
} 

?>
```

I include this file in another php file. And there i just wanna get the information from here. So when I do

```
echo getDescriptionOfPage();
```

I get the Error= ***Undefined variable: titleOfPage in /Applicat....***
I only know the rules from C and JAVA..
Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How would `$titleOfPage` get into the function?  Maybe you want to build a class?

Comment: You could use sessions - put `session_start();` at the top of your page and set your variables as - for example `$_SESSION['autor'] = "Daniel";` and you could `echo $_SESSION['autor'];` on any page you want without the need for any functions - put `session_start();` at the top of each page. You could also return `$_SESSION['autor'];` from your `getAutorOfPage(){` function in the same way if you wanted to.your function as it has the same kind of scope as a global. Sessions tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make a global final variable?

So.. basically you want to define a named constant.

```
define("TITLE_OF_PAGE", "Opinion");

function getTitleOfPage(){
    return TITLE_OF_PAGE;
}
```

But I'm pretty sure that there are no real reasons to do it. :P